# Publish an Infopath 2013 form to Sharepoint 2013 List

Tags: infopath

I need to publish the Infopath form to the Sharepoint List, I searched for the options but didnt get an perfect idea.

Else, can i save the infopath form to the List when click on submit button? How can i acheive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you start the form? If you start with InfoPath Designer, File > New, you need to select the SharePoint List template. It will then prompt you to create a SharePoint list and you can build the form. While you add controls to the form the respective fields will be created in SharePoint. The Quick Publish button will publish the form to the list.

If you start from SharePoint, create the list, the on the List ribbon click "Customize form". This opens the form in InfoPath. You can edit it and then use the Quick Publish option to publish the changes back to the list.

If you have started with InfoPath, you may have created a browser form. You cannot connect a browser form to a list as a list form.

Comment: Anyway i have a blank form with few controls and i published it as form library. But regarding versioning in form library, the modifications in fields are not showing. So i need to move the documents from Form library to List. Help me to sort this out